# Supervisor issue ? Notification cache? Laravel notification (Customizing The Templates) sometimes used old view

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-6, supervisord, laravel-notification

I handle old project laravel 6.*

For sending email I using customize template notification for laravel from
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications#customizing-the-templates

after I run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

It will create folder

> resource/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php

And I custom the file email.blade.php

Something like [after]

```
@component('mail::message')
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {{ $greeting }}
@else
@if ($level === 'error')
# @lang('Whoops!')
@else
# @lang('Hello!')
@endif
@endif

{{-- Intro Lines --}}
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

{{-- Action Button --}}
@isset($actionText)
<?php
    switch ($level) {
        case 'success':
        case 'error':
            $color = $level;
            break;
        default:
            $color = 'yellow';
            break;
    }
?>
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $actionUrl, 'color' => $color])
{{ $actionText }}
@endcomponent
@endisset

{{-- Outro Lines --}}
@foreach ($outroLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

{{-- Salutation --}}
@if (! empty($salutation))
{{ $salutation }}
@else
@lang('Regards'),<br>
UOI Corps <br>
<br>
<br>
<?php
    $icon = config('app.icon_url');
    echo '<table><tr style="padding:13px;"><td style="display:flex; margin-right: 3px;"><img src='.$icon.' width="101px" height="31px"/></td><td><p style="font-size: 14px;">UOI Corps</p></td></tr></table>';
?>
@endif

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($actionText)
@slot('subcopy')
@lang(
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
    'into your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
        'actionURL' => $actionUrl,
    ]
)
@endslot
@endisset
@endcomponent
```

and before editing with new code just different change on: [before]

- $icon => read config('app.icon_url'); icon_url from env and value is just url image.
- change the color 'primary' to 'yellow', here's a code
- some word UOI to UOI Corps

here's file before I change the email.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {{ $greeting }}
@else
@if ($level === 'error')
# @lang('Whoops!')
@else
# @lang('Hello!')
@endif
@endif

{{-- Intro Lines --}}
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

{{-- Action Button --}}
@isset($actionText)
<?php
    switch ($level) {
        case 'success':
        case 'error':
            $color = $level;
            break;
        default:
            $color = 'primary';
            break;
    }
?>
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $actionUrl, 'color' => $color])
{{ $actionText }}
@endcomponent
@endisset

{{-- Outro Lines --}}
@foreach ($outroLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

{{-- Salutation --}}
@if (! empty($salutation))
{{ $salutation }}
@else
@lang('Regards'),<br>
UOI<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php
    $icon = config('app.icon_url');
    echo '<table><tr style="padding:13px;"><td style="display:flex; margin-right: 3px;"><img src='.$icon.' width="101px" height="31px"/></td><td><p style="font-size: 14px;">UOI</p></td></tr></table>';
?>
@endif

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($actionText)
@slot('subcopy')
@lang(
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
    'into your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
        'actionURL' => $actionUrl,
    ]
)
@endslot
@endisset
@endcomponent
```

other information file
on .env file

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=uoi@corps.id
MAIL_FROM_NAME="UOI Corps" -> before change it's "UOI"
```

2. using supervisor to handle queue to send notification mail

Then I faced issue sometimes change are applied and sometimes arte not applied. For example, I got email with word expected as "UOI Corps" and sometimes get old view as word "UOI".
and sender email sometimes "UOI Corps" and sometimes get sender as "UOI"

The issue same on this thread
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/notification-class-cached

What I have done:

- fresh build and restart supervisor
- laravel clear cache and config

> ```
> composer dump-autoload
> php artisan clear-compiled
> php artisan cache:clear
> php artisan view:clear
> php artisan route:clear
> php artisan optimize
> ```

- remove file on folder **bootstrap/cache/***
- remove file on folder **storage/framework/views/***
- re-publish with

> php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications

After all I try it's still issue ?? What anyting else to fix it ??

Thanks.

Comment: update the issue is with queue connection is database, after change too redis. Intermittent doesn't appear. But I don't wanna use redis because it's difficult to manage failed queue